# how to improve searching index in dataframe

Tags: python, performance, pandas, search

Given a pandas dataframe with a timestamp index, sorted.
I have a label and I need to find the closest index to that label.
Also, I need to find a smaller timestamp, so the search should be computed in the minor timestamps.
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = [i for i in range(100)]
dates = pd.date_range(start="01-01-2018", freq="min", periods=100)
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data, dates)

label = "01-01-2018 00:10:01"
method = "pad"
tol = datetime.timedelta(seconds=60)
idx = dataframe.index.get_loc(key=label, method="pad", tolerance=tol)

print("Closest idx:"+str(idx))
print("Closest date:"+str(dataframe.index[idx]))
```

the searching is too slow. Is there a way to improve it?

Comment: "The searching is too low" - what do you mean? Too slow? And what is the "minor" index? Why minor? Do you have a multiindex?

Comment: too slow, sorry.

Comment: Please just provide a [mcve].

Comment: @DYZ with the minor index I tried to said that I need the closest previous index.

Comment: @coldspeed I will add it, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To improve performance, I recommend a transformation of what you're searching.  Instead of using `get_loc`, you can convert your `DateTimeIndex` to Unix Time, and use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) on the underlying `numpy` array (As the name implies, this requires a sorted index).

---

#### `get_loc`:

(Your current approach)

```
label = "01-01-2018 00:10:01"
tol = datetime.timedelta(seconds=60)
idx = dataframe.index.get_loc(key=label, method="pad", tolerance=tol)
print(dataframe.iloc[idx])

0    10
Name: 2018-01-01 00:10:00, dtype: int64
```

And it's timings:

```
%timeit dataframe.index.get_loc(key=label, method="pad", tolerance=tol)
2.03 ms ± 81.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

#### `np.searchsorted`:

```
arr = df.index.astype(int)//10**9
l = pd.to_datetime(label).timestamp()
idx = np.max(np.searchsorted(arr, l, side='left')-1, 0)
print(dataframe.iloc[idx])

0    10
Name: 2018-01-01 00:10:00, dtype: int64
```

And the timings:

```
%timeit np.max(np.searchsorted(arr, l, side='left')-1, 0)
56.6 µs ± 979 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

(I didn't include the setup costs, because the initial array creation should be something you do once, then use for every single query, but even if I did include the setup costs, this method is faster):

```
%%timeit
arr = df.index.astype(int)//10**9
l = pd.to_datetime(label).timestamp()
np.max(np.searchsorted(arr, l, side='left')-1, 0)

394 µs ± 3.84 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

The above method *does not* enforce a tolerance of `60s`, although this is trivial to check:

```
>>> np.abs(arr[idx]-l)<60
True
```